# It is possible to have chromium permanently raised and make requests through php

Tags: puppeteer

I am developing an application to collect certain content with chrome-headdless using puppeteer. And I would like to know if it is possible to have an instance of chromiun permanently lifted and be passing works to him to collect the contents. That is to say, not to do the launch for each task but to do it at the beginning, something such as:

```
var puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

class Instancia
{
     constructor()
     {
         const width = 1920;
         const height = 1080;
         const useragent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:59.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/59.0';

        this.browser = null;
        this.page = null;

        this.init = async function()
        {
            this.browser = await puppeteer.launch({
                args: ['--no-sandbox', `--window-size=${ width },${ height }`],
                headless: false,
                executablePath: '/usr/bin/chromium',
                devtools: false,
                slowMo: 20
            });
            this.page = await this.browser.newPage();

            await this.page.setUserAgent(useragent);
            await this.page.setViewport({
                width,
                height
            });
        }

        this.goTo = async function(url)
        {
            console.log(url);
            console.log(this.page);
            await this.page.goto(url);
        }

    }
}

var browserObj = new Instancia();
browserObj.init();
browserObj.goTo('https://www.example.com/');
```

Comment: You should be more precise in your question. Because for now, my answer is: "yes".

Answer (score 0):

In all the examples that can be found, one launches puppeteer and then performs various actions. This causes the browser to be lifted, actions performed and then the browser is closed. If one has to collect information about 100 urls this means that 100 instances of chrome will be opened. If this happens in a short period of time, it can significantly affect server performance.

My question is whether it would be possible to have a chrome running permanently and open tabs for each url in the queue, perform the actions and close the tab not the browser itself.

In the sample code proposed when you call `browserObj. goTo (' https://www.example.com/');` you get the message:

`(node:9355) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'goto' of null.`

Then you cannot access the page object from the instance.

What I want to know is if it is possible to have an instance of the browser open on one side and for example from a php file run something like this:

```
shell_exec('node myFile. js url css_selectors');
```

to run myFile. js which contains some instructions like:

```
page.goto(url);
const pageContent = await page.content();
return pageContent;
```